# Pass multiple parameters in HTTP DELETE request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass the `id` and `dept` field in a DELETE HTTP request and fetch inside `deleteData()` but I'm receiving null in `deleteData()` for `id` and `dept`.

```
$http['delete']('webapi/Data/delete?' + cdata.id + "&&" + cdata.lineUp)

@DELETE()
@Path("/delete")
public String deleteData(@QueryParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("dept") String dept){
```

Comment: I think you need more context around the problem.

Answer (score 7):

`HTTP Delete` does not accept data as an argument.

**Won't Work**

Otherwise, I would pass an object like so:

```
var cdata = {
   id: 2,
   lineUp: [...]
};

// won't work
$http.delete('webapi/Data/delete, cdata)
  .then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
  })
  .then(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
  });
```

If you wanted to be truly **RESTful**, you shouldn't need to pass anything to the `HTTP Delete` method besides the `id`.

**RESTFul**

```
var cdata = {
   id: 2,
   lineUp: [...]
};

// RESTful
$http.delete('webapi/Data/delete/' + cdata.id)
  .then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
  })
  .then(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
  });
```

You can, however, use `HTTP Post` as a workaround.

**Workaround**

```
var cdata = {
   id: 2,
   lineUp: [...]
};

// workaround
$http.post('webapi/Data/delete, cdata)
  .then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
  })
  .then(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
  });
```